# Scaling output with for loop

Tags: java, math, for-loop

What I'm trying to do is make a box, like so:

```
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
```

and the code for it is

```
public static void drawUpper(int count)
{
    System.out.print("|");

    for(int i = 0; i <= (count); i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= (-count + 1); i++){
        System.out.print("/\\");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= (-count + 1); i++){
        System.out.print("/\\");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    System.out.print("|");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void drawLower(int count)
{
    System.out.print("|");

    for(int i = 0; i <= -count; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= (count + 1); i++){
        System.out.print("\\/");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= -count; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= -count; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= (count + 1); i++){
        System.out.print("\\/");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= -count; i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }

    System.out.print("|");
    System.out.println();
}
```

However, this needs to be at a scale, its current scale, is 5;

```
private static int size = 5;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i = 1; i > (-size / 2); i--){
        drawUpper(i);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i > (-size / 2); i--){
        drawLower(i);
    }
}
```

Now, so long as the scale doesn't change it works perfectly, and I'm quite pleased with myself. However when i change the scale to 7 the box seems to turn into this:

```
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
|............|
```

However, it's supposed to look like this:

```
|....../\............/\......|
|...../\/\........../\/\.....|
|..../\/\/\......../\/\/\....|
|.../\/\/\/\....../\/\/\/\...|
|../\/\/\/\/\..../\/\/\/\/\..|
|./\/\/\/\/\/\../\/\/\/\/\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/\/\/\/\/..\/\/\/\/\/\/.|
|..\/\/\/\/\/....\/\/\/\/\/..|
|...\/\/\/\/......\/\/\/\/...|
|....\/\/\/........\/\/\/....|
|.....\/\/..........\/\/.....|
|......\/............\/......|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. I only provided code for producing one diamond (I won't do all the work for you `;)`). It's trivial to adapt it to produce two diamonds, so it's up to you to make those changes (it's really not difficult at all, given the code below).

```
// aliases for java's verbose methods
public static void p(char c) { System.out.print(c); }
public static void pn(char c) { System.out.println(c); }

// convenient shortcut for alternating between characters
public static char[] a = {'/', '\\'};

public static void dotop(int size, int line) {
    p('|');
    for (int i=0; i<size-line; i++) p('.');
    for (int i=0; i<line+1; i++) p(a[i%2]);
    for (int i=0; i<line+1; i++) p(a[(i+1+line)%2]);
    for (int i=0; i<size-line; i++) p('.');
    pn('|');
}

public static void dobottom(int size, int line) {
    p('|');
    for (int i=0; i<size-line; i++) p('.');
    for (int i=0; i<line+1; i++) p(a[(i+line+(line+1)%2)%2]);
    for (int i=0; i<line+1; i++) p(a[(i+1+(line+1)%2)%2]);
    for (int i=0; i<size-line; i++) p('.');
    pn('|');
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 4;
    for (int i=0; i<=size; i++) dotop(size, i);
    for (int i=0; i<=size; i++) dobottom(size, size-i);
}
```

The produced output is:

```
|..../\....|
|.../\/\...|
|../\/\/\..|
|./\/\/\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/\/\/.|
|..\/\/\/..|
|...\/\/...|
|....\/....|
```

Comment: The original scale is 5, so its not that its uneven?

Comment: The number of produced rows is 6. Also realize that integer division is occurring. You will get the same result for a scale of 4 *and* 5. (You shouldn't be using odd scales).

Comment: Hm, I see. What should i do then?

Comment: Whoops. I made a huge mistake. Let me fix.

Comment: I'm working on it myself right now and will try to get back soon. Counting is tricky >.<. A helpful observation is that the two diamonds are always going to be identical, so you'll be repeating the same drawing methods twice on each line.

Comment: Done! Take a look see.

Comment: Please read my answer. I told you it's up to you to modify it to print two diamonds. It's not difficult.

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. I've been fiddling with it for about half an hour.

Comment: You need to pick apart my code to understand which parts print what. Find the code that prints `..../\....` and make changes so it prints `..../\......../\....` (hint, the target line is my line printed *twice*). It may be too much of a giveaway to even say that the additional code you may need to write on your own is minimal. A line completes when `pn()` is called. You need to print something before it gets called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48427/discussion-between-collinjsimpson-and-robby-catron)